# VBA Compile error What is the cause and solution?

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Set myIE = New InternetExplorer
    myIE.Silent = True
    myIE.navigate sURL
    myIE.Visible = False

    Do While myIE.Busy
        Do Until myIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Set HTMLDoc = myIE.document
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginID").Value = ICUSER
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Value = ICPASS
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    ' Read and Write Data to the reports
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

I have been using this code for a while and It works just fine on my computer, but when I share the file with others some computers can not run the code and gives this error. Any one know the solution to this issue, please help.

Comment: Is the other computer running a different version of excel?

Comment: The other computer is running the same excel version and I have checked the vba references also and found the same.

Comment: Have you checked (Tools>References...) that the references mentioned in the code are sill set?

Comment: Last resort is to to change the order of the references
 (Tools menu in vb window). Just trial
 and error.

Comment: Is the other computer running a different version of Internet Explorer? When you share this code is it a copy and paste deal over email, or are you actually sending the excel file?

Comment: Also, what's the actual error. Generally a `Compile Error` comes with more verbiage. I suspect "User defined type not defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that there is a different in versions of Internet Explorer. When faced with version issues between different computers in VBA you can switch from using Tools>>References to Late binding.

To use late binding here change your code from

```
Set myIE = New InternetExplorer
```

To:

```
Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Now, as long as the other computer has any version of Internet Explorer installed, this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the references mentioned in the code are sill set (Tools>References...).  If that doesn't work, last resort is to change the order of the references (Tools menu in vb window). Unfortunately it is just trial and error..